# While running following code, UnsupportedOperationException is thrown at .remove() method

Tags: java, list

While running following code, `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown at `.remove()` method.

By this code:

```
List list = Array.asList(array) ;
list.remove(0);
```

Comment: Indeed. What is your question?

Comment: The first thing you should do every time you have a question about Java is read the documentation.  In this case, you would google ["_java 7 Arrays_"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) and look for the _asList()_ method.  The answer to most questions is in the first sentence.

Answer (score 10):

[Arrays#asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

> Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array

Thus, You can't add/remove elements to/from it.

To overcome this problem, you can do:

```
List modifiableList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove some Object from List of objects its quite analogical way to do it directly. You need to use [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayLIst<>(); // or List<Integer> l = new ArrayLIst<Integer>();
Iterator<Integer> iter = l.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if (iter.next().intValue() == 5) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```